# puppeteer - click anchor containing a span with matching text

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to have puppeteer click the anchor which has a child span that contains certain text.

HTML snippet (with personal details removed by "..."):

```
<a data-url="/accounts/inquiry/accountdetails/..." class="account-title-group column " tabindex="0" role="link">
        <i class="icon acct-tile  checking"></i>
    <span class="account-name OneLinkNoTx" lang="en">
        Checking</span>
    <span class="masked-account-number has-wells-advisor">
        <span class="OneLinkNoTx">...</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

I've tried several variations to no avail:

```
  //const aElementsWithChecking = await page.$x("//a[contains(., 'Checking')]");
  //const aElementsWithChecking = await page.$x("//a[@class='account-title-group' and descendant::span[contains(., 'Checking')]]");
  //const aElementsWithChecking = await page.$x("//a[@class='account-title-group' and descendant::span[contains(text(), 'Checking')]]");
  //const aElementsWithChecking = await page.$x("//a[@class='account-title-group' and .//*[contains(text(), 'Checking')]]");
  //const aElementsWithChecking = await page.$x("//a[@class='account-title-group' and .//*[contains(., 'Checking')]]");
  const aElementsWithChecking = await page.$x("//a[(.//*|.)[.='Checking']]");

  if (aElementsWithChecking.length > 0) {
    await aElementsWithChecking[0].click();
  } else {
    throw new Error("Link not found");
  }
```

Comment: `//a[contains(., 'Checking')]` should have worked. If it wasn't there you probably have to wait for it.

Comment: I have continued troubleshooting in a convo with Abdel.  This errors seems to be the issue `[Report Only] Refused to run the
JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'nonce-........' https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present in the source list.`  Running `page.setBypassCSP(true)` does not resolve the issue.

Comment: `await page.setBypassCSP(true)` ? Also try args:['--disable-web-security'] as a puppeteer option

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to select the anchor tag based on the innerHTML
you got to try:

```
await page.$$eval("a",
                  anchors=>anchors.filter(
                           anchor=>anchor.innerHTML
                                         .includes("checking"))[0].click());
```

Comment: I tried the original suggestion but actually got an error `TypeError: anchors[0].click is not a function`.  I'm clearly out of my element here.

Comment: I tried a similar case on my machine and it worked
if you could send the URL, I may help you

Comment: try with the last edit and tell if any errors occur

Comment: wellsfargo.com (which will obviously only work if you have an account there).  I tried your updated code.  It doesn't err out (which all of mine did), but it doesn't actually click the link either.

Comment: you could try to `console.log(anchors[0])` to see if its the right one in the `page.$$eval` callback

Comment: anchors is not defined outside of that expression.  I reverted back to the original: 
```const anchors = await page.$$eval("a",anchors=>anchors.filter(anchor=>anchor.innerHTML.includes("checking")));

console.log(anchors[0])
``` and just got {}

Comment: try this:
`await page.$$eval("a", (anchors) =>{
    anchors = anchors.filter((anchor) => anchor.innerHTML.includes("checking"))
    console.log(anchors[0])
  }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229608/discussion-between-senorsmile-and-abdel-kader-glt).